# Is it possible to detect and intercept an outgoing SMS message using a BroadcastReceiver in Android 13?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am a college student working on their capstone project and was wondering whether it was possible in recent versions of Android, specifically Android 13, to intercept and potentially block an SMS message before it is sent. If so, how would one implement something such as a BroadcastReceiver in order to detect such a thing and keep it from being sent? All the research I've done so far leads me to the conclusion that it is not possible to detect an SMS message being sent on android, as no broadcast is made of such a thing happening, but all the sources I get on that claim are old StackOverflow messages from a decade ago or more. Can anyone confirm whether or not I am correct in my assumption, and if not, how would I go about implementing such a functionality?

I have attempted to create a BroadcastReceiver method for detecting when a text message for a certain blocked number is sent, and everything appeared to be in order. However, nothing seemed to occur, even though the method was run through, and I could still send messages to the allegedly blocked number. I am not sure if it's even something that can be done on Android anymore, if it ever was, based on the aforementioned decade-old StackOverflow threads and the recent changes to the API.

Comment: Not unless you're the default SMS app.  Possibly not even then-  it would work for texts via the texting app, but might not work via programatically sending a text.